# No bean named is defined

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am using JUnit to test Component of Spring,throws error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'wsVehicleService' is defined
```

This is my test class:

```
package com.zw.ws.service.impl;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/*.xml")    
public class WsVehicleServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Test
    public void getHistoryAlarmInfo() throws Exception {
        try {
            String requestJson = "\"{\"VEHICLEID\":\"cae21196-cb66-4256-88a6-7cdfb23e2c78\",\"STARTTIME\":1476115200,\"ENDTIME\":1476201599,\"TYPE\":1}\"";
            WsVehicleService vehicleService = (WsVehicleService) ctx.getBean("wsVehicleService");
            vehicleService.getHistoryAlarmInfoImpl(requestJson);
        } catch (BeansException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class will be tested:

```
@Component
public class WsVehicleService {

    public List<HistoryAlarmInfo> getHistoryAlarmInfo(String requestJson) {
        try {
            return getHistoryAlarmInfoImpl(requestJson);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

When JUnit run to getBean,throws error:`No bean named 'wsVehicleService' is defined`.
Where is going wrong?What could I do to make it right?

What I having tried:

add `@ComponentScan("com.zw.ws.*")` to scan the WsVehicleService class.

This is the log:

```
    12:53:11.098]-[main]-[org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener]-{After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@58783f6c testClass = WsVehicleServiceTest, testInstance = com.zw.ws.service.impl.WsVehicleServiceTest@7577b641, testMethod = getHistoryAlarmInfo@WsVehicleServiceTest, testException = org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'wsVehicleService' is defined, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@3a7b503d testClass = WsVehicleServiceTest, locations = '{classpath:/*.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null], method annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].}

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'wsVehicleService' is defined

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at com.zw.ws.service.impl.WsVehicleServiceTest.getHistoryAlarmInfo(WsVehicleServiceTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:253)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


            12:53:11.107]-[main]-[org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener]-{After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@58783f6c testClass = WsVehicleServiceTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@3a7b503d testClass = WsVehicleServiceTest, locations = '{classpath:/*.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].}
```

PS:This is no XML configuration,all beans are using autoscan.

Comment: `@ComponentScan` must be added to your test class!

Comment: Please Show your XML configruration and add the package names

Comment: @Dolphin: Have a look into my answer and let me know if it is  working for you.

Comment: @Unknown It don't work right now,but I'll keep trying. I have aready trying all way according the answer,because it is a working project and configuration is a little complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)First Solution:

`@ContextConfiguration` initializes the Spring context and by default looks for a Spring XML file in the same package as the unit test with the file name the same as the class with '-context.xml' as a suffix

Try adding the WsVehicleServiceTest-context.xml file in `com.mycompany.annotation` package.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

      <bean id="wsVehicleService"
          class="com.mycompany.annotation.WsVehicleService">
      </bean>

</beans>
```

Junit test class after removing ("classpath:/*.xml"):

```
package com.mycompany.annotation;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class WsVehicleServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Test
    public void getHistoryAlarmInfo() throws Exception {
        try {
            WsVehicleService vehicleService = (WsVehicleService) ctx
                    .getBean("wsVehicleService");
            String hi = vehicleService.sayHi();
            System.out.println(hi);
        } catch (BeansException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you want to use `@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/*.xml")` make sure you put

```
<bean id="wsVehicleService"
              class="com.mycompany.annotation.WsVehicleService">
</bean>
```

in any one of your *.xml file

2) Second Solution:

Make sure you put `<context:annotation-config />` in your xml file. Here you do not need to declare the wsVehicleService bean in your xml file.

Modify your test class by using `@Autowired` on `WsVehicleService`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/*.xml")   
public class WsVehicleServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Autowired
    WsVehicleService wsVehicleService;

    @Test
    public void getHistoryAlarmInfo() throws Exception {
        try {
            String hi = wsVehicleService.sayHi();
            System.out.println(hi);
        } catch (BeansException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

3) Third solution:

You have mentioned, you do not use any xml configuration files and your exception tells `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`

One reason your WsVehicleService may not exist in the context – is that it may be defined in a package that is not scanned by Spring.

Make sure your WsVehicleService exist in `@ComponentScan("com.mycompany.annotation")` package.

1) Application configuration class with annotation [@Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)

```
package com.mycompany.annotation;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mycompany.annotation")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

2) Your service class

```
package com.mycompany.annotation;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class WsVehicleService {
    public String sayHi(){
        return "HI !!!!!!!!!!";
    }
}
```

3)Junit test class

```
package com.mycompany.annotation;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
public class WsVehicleServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Test
    public void getHistoryAlarmInfo() throws Exception {
        try {
            WsVehicleService vehicleService = (WsVehicleService) ctx
                    .getBean("wsVehicleService");
            String hi = vehicleService.sayHi();
            System.out.println(hi);
        } catch (BeansException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
HI !!!!!!!!!!
```

For more info you can refer [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) and [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts)

More reference for [causes and possible solution for NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception)

Answer (score 9):

"No bean named 'xxx' is defined" is thrown when:

- Your bean has a different name.
- Your bean isn't actually in the context.

Since you haven't changed the default name of the bean, then must be that the bean isn't properly loaded.

You need to indicate where are your components to be scanned (xml config or @Configuration class) and be loaded when run your tests. 
I would create a config class and then add this new config class in the ContextConfiguration annotation (or use xml if you prefer).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.zw.ws"})
public class AppTestConfig {}
```

Your test class then:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={AppTestConfig.class}) 
public class WsVehicleServiceTest {
...
}
```

You can also anotate with `@Autowire` your service and let Spring do the wiring work.

Answer (score 6):

Change line

```
WsVehicleService vehicleService = (WsVehicleService) ctx.getBean(WsVehicleService .class);
```

or

```
@Component("wsVehicleService")
public class WsVehicleService{

//..

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Annotation code

```
//main class    
//@Import(value=AppConfig.class)     
public class AppAnno {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new  
 AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);  
    TodayDate date = ctx.getBean("todayDate",TodayDate.class);   
System.out.println(date.getTodyDate());     
    }     
}    

@Configuration  
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.cb.service.anno","com.cb.dao.anno"})
```

change it according to your basepackage

```
public class AppConfig {  
    @Bean 
public Date date(){    
return new Date();   
}    
}  

import java.util.Date;     
import javax.inject.Named;   
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;    
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;   
@Component     
@Named("todayDate")//you have to add inject jar to your build path     
public class TodayDate {      
@Autowired    
    Date date;    
    public String getTodyDate(){     
    return date.toString( );    
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If We are using `Component` based annotation we have to provide the package path as follows in that configLocation `.xml` as

`<context:component-scan base-package="org.example.javaconfig"/>`

which solved my problem